# Getting the selected value from a select tag

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get the value of the selected option from my select. And I am trying to see it's output through a javascript echo. Here's what I've got so far. I am not getting the value

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <select class="form-control" name="empSel" id="empSel">
   <?php
       $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        $result = mysql_query($sql2) or die("Couldn't execute sql2");
         while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row2['lastname'] ?>"><?= 
    /*$row2['user_surname']."  ".*/
    $row2['id']."-".$row2['lastname'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>

     <Label> Confirm</Label>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info"
          name="submit"/>
     </div>
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $userid = $_POST['empSel'];
  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert('.$userid.')</script>';
  $userid = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $userid);

  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM employee where id ='userid'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql2) or die("Couldn't execute sql2");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("")</script>';
  }
}
?>
```

An javascript alert doesn't pop out on this code. However, when I switch the value in the echo to a different variable an alert pops up. What does it mean? Do I properly get the value of my select and the page refreshed instantly that I didn't get to see it? Thanks

Edit:

An example of the option value would be 1-Lastname
And here's what I've tried.

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['empSel'])){
   $userid = $_POST['empSel'];
  $userid = intval($userid);
   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert('.$userid.')</script>';
}
?>
```

Now the javascript alert shows, but it echo 0. I think I am still not getting the value of my selected option

Comment: try `echo "<script type="text/javascript"> alert('$userid')</script>";
`

Comment: And make sure `value="<?php echo $row2['lastname'] ?>"` is filled in in your HTML, and its not `value=""`

Comment: echo "<script type="text/javascript"> alert('$userid')</script>"; this doesn't work syntax error, unexpected '$userid' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @Tallboy yup it is filled in html. the view is working properly i just cant get the value of the selected option to echo

Comment: Maybe this comment is off-topic but I hope you are not starting a project with this structure. This can be a mess if the project grows this way.

Comment: @MikeVelazco this is a school related thing just need to get this done by now

Comment: Validate the `empSel`, not the `submit` on the if isset part

Comment: I tried to, can you check on my update? I updated my code

Comment: I see the code with no changes

Comment: @MikeVelazco try to refresh the page, thanks!

Comment: Is because the value lastName is an string?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <option value="<?php echo $row2['id'] ?>">
```

This fixed it. In my previous code the option value was the surname...